# What is my best path forward for shaking off my question ban?

Tags: support, post-ban

I've been question banned off and on for the last few years, and as far as I can tell I've somewhat gotten the hang of creating proper questions and researching my problems before posting. However, since I've been on the site since I was a novice programmer, my older questions (since deleted or dissociated) are still plaguing me with question bans, and I can only post a question every 6 months. I accept this, and the question bans have helped me grow as a developer and as an individual. However, I still need to be able to post questions.

I have gone through all of my 5 questions (none with downvotes, several with upvotes) and edited them until I was happy with them. It's been months or years since then though, and since they're old questions no one is going to go back to them and upvote them. I also have been answering questions, doing my best to give back to the community, but I'm not sure those count towards my question ban.

What is my best path going forward from here to be able to fully use the site?

Comment: Maybe edit your deleted questions (a mod can give you a list). But if your latest questions have been well received, you may be digging yourself out of the hole just by carrying on this way. Each new well received question will help your overall score.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε That does not answer my question, simply because I have already taken many of the actions advised in that post (believe me, I've read it enough times over the past couple years). Thank you though

Comment: But there is no other course of action but the one explained there: edit your existing questions so there are better received, post well received questions. The algorithm is automatic. Not sure what are you looking for if you are already well versed on the advise in that Q&A.

Comment: Actually, now that I go back and read it through again, that does indeed answer my question. Sorry about that

Comment: A mod may still see your question here and give you a list of your deleted, negatively scored questions so you can see if any of those is salvageable.

Comment: That would be good. Is there a way I can request that?

Comment: A question like this is very often request enough. When a mod sees it, they will very likely oblige with the list.

Comment: @Isaac It appears you're no longer Q banned (possibly as you received a couple of up votes today - which may or may not have stemmed from posting here on meta). It's going to mean you're still very borderline on being able to fall back into being banned again - so make sure your next Q is as good as you can make it.

Comment: I also suggest to continue the other actions you can do, voting, flagging, suggesting edits, answering as those count as positive contributions and while they don't directly influence a quality ban they do help you recognize valuable content and I imagine that helps quality wise in asking a question that is well received by the community.

Comment: @JonClements Oh awesome, thank you for letting me know! I always try to make sure my questions are as good as possible these days, some of my early questions were quite stupid. (Who needs to initialize multiple variables with the same name but different types? That's dumb.)

Comment: @rene Thank you for letting me know, I've especially been trying my best to vote, flag, and edit as much as I can. It helps out the site and gives me something to do :D